# How to use Jest __mocks__ to mock react-router-dom in a monorepo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am unable to mock `react-router-dom`, I am seeing an error because the mock isn't being instansiated. Where am I going wrong?:

I have a monorepo structured as such, apps are created with `CRA` and use `craco` at the root:

```
|── node_modules
└── applications
        |── myFirstApp
        |      └── src
        |           └── components
        |                    └── MyComponent.js
        |                    └── MyComponent.spec.js
        |── mySecondApp
        |      └── src
        |           └── components
        |                    └── MyComponent.js
        |                    └── MyComponent.spec.js
        └── myThirdApp
               └── src
                    └── components
                             └── MyComponent.js
                             └── MyComponent.spec.js
```

```js
// applications/myFirstApp/src/components/MyComponent.js

import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class NavigationProviderBase extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      *foo*
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(NavigationProviderBase);
```

If I mock the dependency in the `spec` file everything works as expected:

```js
// applications/myFirstApp/src/components/MyComponent.spec.js

import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import React from "react";
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent";

jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
  withRouter: (component) => component,
}));

describe("MyComponent", () => {
  it("should do stuff", () => {
    render(<MyComponent />);
  });
});
```

However, I don't want to be repeating the import in multiple `spec` files so I am looking at Jest's manual mocking feature: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks

I have changed my folder structure to be:

```
|── node_modules
|── __mocks__ 
|       └── react-router-dom.js
└── applications
        |── myFirstApp
        |      └── src
        |           └── components
        |                    └── MyComponent.js
        |                    └── MyComponent.spec.js
        |── mySecondApp
        |      └── src
        |           └── components
        |                    └── MyComponent.js
        |                    └── MyComponent.spec.js
        └── myThirdApp
               └── src
                    └── components
                             └── MyComponent.js
                             └── MyComponent.spec.js
```

With the mock file containing:

```js
// __mocks__/react-router-dom.js

const reactRouterDom = jest.createMockFromModule("react-router-dom");

reactRouterDom.withRouter = ({ children }) => children;

module.exports = reactRouterDom;
```

And the `spec` file now like:

```js
// applications/myFirstApp/src/components/MyComponent.spec.js

import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import React from "react";
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent";

describe("MyComponent", () => {
  it("should do stuff", () => {
    render(<MyComponent />);
  });
});
```

However, when running the tests now I receive the error:

```
Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(MyComponent) /> outside a <Router>
```

Which indicates to me that `react-router-dom` is no longer being mocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it. The problem was that `__mocks__` wasn't in scope in the project `jest.config.js` `roots`

`roots: ["<rootDir>", "<rootDir>/../../__mocks__"]`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mocking, you could use `MemoryRouter` component as a wrapper to your test component.